# JSON file too short to create a JsonReader

Tags: java, json

I'm using the javax.json library and am trying to read a JsonObject in a text file. I'm using this method to read a file and return it as a JsonObject:

```
public static JsonObject readFile(String path)
{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is);
    JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
    rdr.close();
    return obj;
}
```

However, when I try to read a file, I get an error at the `JsonReader rdr = Json.createReader(is)` line stating that it

> "Cannot auto-detect encoding, not enough chars".

Is there anything I can do to fix this error without changing what's in the file?

The files are like this:

`{"6111":1,"6121":1,"6131":1,"6141":1,"6151":1,"6162":1,"6312":1,"6323":1,"6331":1,"6343":1,"totalGames":1}`

Comment: how is this file created? you should define encoding when you save files.

Comment: @new The file is created by using PrintWriter with the encoding defined when I saved the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated the method `createReader()` needs more characters to detect file charset

while your file is too small to allow that, you can pass the charset to the method

try this:

```
public static JsonObject readFile(String path)
{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    JsonReader rdr = Json.createParserFactory(null).createReader(is, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    JsonObject obj = rdr.readObject();
    rdr.close();
    return obj;
}
```

if you are using different charset than "UTF8" change that for the used one

Comment: The createReader method only takes an InputStream as its parameter so I can't add the charset like that.

Comment: @StevenT you can set the encoding on your InputStream use 

new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathToFile), <encoding>).

Comment: sorry, this should be called on instance of `JsonReaderFactory` i will look for a sample and update the answer

Comment: @Yazan Updated with creating the parserfactory

Comment: @StevenT please check the updated answer, Thank you Oskar!

Comment: Hello everyone. Thanks for all the help but I'm now getting an error stating that "Invalid token EOF at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0), Expected Tokens [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]" with the file I posted above. I believe it's because the JsonObject in the text file is printed in one line. Is there also a way to fix this without changing the file?

Comment: @StevenT i am not sure about this one, you may inspect the content of the file using some advanced editor (edit++) maybe and see is something is wrong, mainly first character of the file ?!

Comment: I recreated all the files by including "UTF-8" in the PrintWriter and it fixed everything. Thanks everyone!